# Level Translator Impedance Matching Termination Resistor For High Speed?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, level-shifting, impedance-matching, termination

I want to connect level translators like 74LVC1T45 to a microcontroller to translate high speed signals from 3.3v to 5v. I want to make sure it works for frequencies up to 40 MHz. The traces on the PCB can end up to be as long as 15cm.

Do I need to worry about impedance matching between the microcontroller and 74LVC1T45 to reduce reflections?
The worry is I don't want to generate noise in the power rails or cross talk with other traces and hope this can be be reduced or eliminated with correct termination resistors.

Comment: It's on the cusp of being problematic without some form of termination.

Comment: You are on Lambda/50 .....Hmm I think you can get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to worry about impedance matching between the
> microcontroller and 74LVC1T45 to reduce reflections?

No, because the source driver has no characteristic impedance. In addition, transmission line effects usually don't have an affect until ~50MHz.

What will affect the signals is capacitance which will affect the rise times, so try and keep that low.